# Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value whereas I return new Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why am I getting "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" ?
I can't understand. Maybe I'm missing something.

```
function getImage(url) {
  console.log('Begin get image');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  https.get(url, res => {
    // Initialise an array
    const bufs = [];

    // Add the data to the buffer collection
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('on data image');
      bufs.push(chunk)
    });

    // This signifies the end of a request
    res.on('end', function () {
      console.log('on end image');

      // We can join all of the 'chunks' of the image together
      const data = Buffer.concat(bufs);

      resolve(data);
    });
  })
    // Inform the callback of the error.
    .on('error', function (error) {
      reject(error);
    });
});
}
```

Here is where I call the function :

```
getImage(imageURL)
      .then( dataImg => {
        console.log('image get get');
        (...)
      }
```

I should get the dataImg and make operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following code using node and received the image-buffer. Maybe check if you missed some brackets somewhere.

```
var https = require("https");

function getImage(url) {
    console.log('Begin get image');

    // Return the loading-promise
    return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, (res) => {
                // Initialise an array to store the image-data
                const bufs = [];

                // Add the data to the buffer collection
                res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    console.log('on data image');
                    // Push the recieved chunks into the array
                    bufs.push(chunk)
                });

                // This signifies the end of a request
                res.on('end', function() {
                    console.log('on end image');

                    // We can join all of the 'chunks' of the image together
                    const data = Buffer.concat(bufs);

                    // Return the image-buffer
                    resolve(data);
                });
            })
            // Inform the callback of the error.
            .on('error', function(error) {
                reject(error);
            });
    }));
}

(function() {
    getImage("https://preview.redd.it/utrlx02sx2431.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=8ed20013607e0d6019f59ab01b0e4930eb913351")
        .then((dataImg) => {
            console.log('image get get');
            console.log(dataImg);
        });
})();
```

Console-Output:

```
ab@xy:~/test$ node testrun.js 
Begin get image
on data image
on data image
on end image
image get get
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff e1 00 42 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 01 87 69 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 ... 20311 more bytes>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes in fact it's in my then clause that I have an error. I tried to input my retrieved data as a base 64 image which is not...